# Embedding 509 cert info into xml file

Tags: c#

I have c# code to sign an xml that is very similar to this post:
[Java equivalent of C# XML signing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330049/java-equivalent-of-c-sharp-xml-signing-method)

Specifically, I am interested in this section:

```
// embed public key information for signature validation purposes
KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoX509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate, X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot);
keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoX509Data);
signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
```

My question is, does this code embed any private key information in the xml file? The comment of the code implies that it does not, which is good. I do not want to be embedding private key data in my xml file. But I am rather new to signing and it would be very bad if I did include private key data so I thought I would ask here. I tried first checking the microsoft doc on KeyInfoX509Data here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t95xse03.aspx ,but that did not answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificates usually only hold the public key, though there's a possibility the private key is in there if the certificate started in PKCS#12 format.  If 'certificate' is an X509Certificate2 object, you can always look up the property HasPrivateKey to know for sure if there's any private key info in that certificate.