# How to create a detached digital signature for an XML in Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, xml

I have created a digital signature using PFX file for an XML document with the help of [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330049/java-equivalent-of-c-sharp-xml-signing-method?rq=1). All I want to know is how to make it a detached digital signature so that it could be passed to XML signature tag? Right now, it is enveloped in my XML file (i.e. Enveloped signature).

Answer (score 0):

Use Google. I have found an example in 10 seconds.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/xmldsig/api/javax/xml/crypto/doc-files/GenDetached.java